Combine Mindstorms and NXT/RCX tags
What should we do?
 - Keep: [tag:nxt] and [tag:rcx];    Unusable/'Reserved': [tag:mindstorms]

                                      OR

 - Keep: [tag:mindstorms];           Tag synonyms:        [tag:nxt] and [tag:rcx]


In other words, should we 'combine' nxt and rcx into mindstorms?

@Ambo100 Tags names do not contain any magiscules. :)

I think RCX and NXT are two sufficiently apart technologies that they will each require its specific tag, so I really don't like having nxt and rcx being synonyms for mindstorms.
However, there might be questions which aren't so much about a specific Mindstorms kit but rather about robotic design in a more general sense. If these questions happen, taging them with rcx or nxt will be ill-suited, while mindstorms might be better — although there maybe robotics would be best (let's not forget Spybotics :-).
My own suggestion is to keep all three tags for the moment, but specify in the mindstorms wiki that if the question is specific to the NXT or RCX, then the appropriate tags should be used.
But really, I think we don't have a sufficient vision of what questions will arise to make that kind of decision now. Then again, I'm tagnostic, so my advise isn't worth squat here.

Or [tag:WeDo] which also fits into Robotics.

I've removed my votes on the NXT/RCX synonyms and adjusted the Wiki body to include a note about using the technology specific tags.

The way you did it is exactly what I had in mind

Or Cybermaster and Scout. :)
